# Reorder ggplot in decreasing and show only top 5 count

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

```
ggplot(profiles) +
 aes(x = Location, fill = Gender) +
 geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
 scale_fill_hue(direction = 1) +
 labs(title = "Locations of Users") +
 theme_light() +
 theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", 
 hjust = 0.5), axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold"), axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

How do I edit this so it sort by decreasing order on my plot and show only top 5 counts?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the below code chunk is a bit tidier, based on Shawn's simulated dataset.

```
profiles %>%  
  group_by(Location, Gender) %>% 
  summarise(total = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Location = fct_reorder(Location, total, .desc = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(Location %in% c(.$Location %>% levels() %>% .[1:5])) %>%   
  ggplot(aes(x = Location, y = total,  fill = Gender)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_hue(direction = 1) +
  labs(title = "Locations of Users") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.5), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

Comment: I like this option too.

Answer (score 0):

#### Simulating Your Data

I'm not totally sure what your data structure is (you should provide a minimally reproducible dataset next time), but I have simulated a dataset I think may be similar and you can try to tinker with this to see if it works for you. First, I set the seed to a random number and made up a fake dataset below that may be reproducible:

```
#### Set Seed for Replication ####
set.seed(123)

#### Create Data ####
profiles <- data.frame(Gender = round(rbinom(n=1000,
                                 size=1,
                                 prob = .5)),
                 Location = round(rbinom(n=1000,
                                       size=6,
                                       prob = .5))) %>% 
  mutate(Gender = as.factor(ifelse(Gender == 0,
                         "Male",
                         "Female")),
         Location = as.factor(ifelse(Location == 0,
                           "Farm",
                           ifelse(Location == 1,
                                  "Zoo",
                                  ifelse(Location == 3,
                                         "School",
                                         ifelse(Location == 4,
                                                "Library",
                                                ifelse(Location == 5,
                                                       "Prison",
                                                       "Factory")))))))
```

You can check the first 10 lines of data with this:

```
head(profiles,10) # check data
```

Which should look something similar to this:

```
   Gender Location
1    Male  Factory
2    Male   Prison
3    Male   School
4  Female   School
5    Male  Factory
6  Female  Library
7    Male  Library
8    Male   School
9    Male  Library
10   Male  Library
```

#### Checking Counts

Then from there I checked to see what the counts were in descending order:

```
#### Plot Arranged Bar ####
profiles %>% 
  group_by(Location) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  arrange(desc(n))  # Farm has lowest count, Zoo next
```

Shown below:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
# Groups:   Location [6]
  Location     n
  <fct>    <int>
1 School     301
2 Factory    253
3 Library    232
4 Prison     105
5 Zoo         92
6 Farm        17
```

From there I reordered the levels by count:

```
profiles$Location <- factor(profiles$Location,
                            levels = c("School",
                                       "Factory",
                                       "Library",
                                       "Prison",
                                       "Zoo",
                                       "Farm"))
```

#### Plotting Data

Finally I plotted by first filtering Farm out, then using the new reordering:

```
#### Plot Desc Order ####
profiles %>% 
  filter(!Location == "Farm") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x =Location, 
      fill = Gender)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_hue(direction = 1) +
  labs(title = "Locations of Users") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", 
                                  hjust = 0.5), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

Which should give you something like this:

[image]